# NgFor over observable not showing any items from NGRX Store

Tags: javascript, angular, redux

I'm trying to learn NGRX Store and got some problems when it comes to showing the items in my store in the template.

The store seems to work as expected. I see that it gets updated when I dispatch an action so I think I'm doing something wrong in my component when I want to show the todo-list in this example.

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let todo of (todoList$ | async)">Current Count: {{ todo.task }}</div>
<div>
  <button (click)="addTodo()">Add</button>
</div>
```

TS:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Store} from '@ngrx/store';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

import * as TodoActions from './todo/store/todo.actions';
import {Todo} from './todo/todo.model';
import {State} from './todo/store/todo.reducers';

@Component({
  selector: 'todo-list',
  templateUrl: './todo-list.component.html'
})
export class TodoListComponent {
  todoList$: Observable<Todo[]>;

  constructor(private store: Store<State>) {
    this.todoList$ = store.select('todos');
  }

  addTodo() {
    this.store.dispatch(new TodoActions.AddTodo(new Todo('Finish todo-list', false)));
  }
}
```

Where am I doing something wrong?

Check out this stackblitz for full code example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-test

Thanks!

Comment: Try removing the parenthesis: `*ngFor="let todo of todoList$ | async"`

Comment: `store.select('todoList').map(x => x.todos)`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-test-vel7f2?file=app/todo-list/todo-list.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The store did work as it should in terms of adding `Todo`s, but access to the store was not properly set up.

In your `app.module.ts` file, you had your store set up as `StoreModule.forRoot({ todoList: todoReducer })`, which means that you cannot access your state with `store.select('todos');`.

You can test this by putting this line in your constructor, just before the `store.select('todos');` line:

`store.select(state => state).subscribe( val => console.log(val));`

This should print out something like `{todoList: {todos:[...]}}`, which means that you cannot access your `State` with `store.select('todos');` selection.

A couple of changes needed to be made on your code.

First of all, change on your `todoReducer` function:

```
export function todoReducer(todos: Todo[] = initialState, action: TodoActions.TodoActions): Todo[] {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TodoActions.ADD_TODO:
      console.log({
        todos: [...todos, action.payload]
      });
      return  [...todos, action.payload];
    default:
      return todos;
  }
}
```

Now, this function handles `Todo`s, not `State`.

Second, I've added a const value `tdReducer` of type `ActionReducerMap<State>` like this:

```
export const tdReducer: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
  todos: todoReducer
}
```

Finally, I've changed the entry in the `app.module.ts` file to this:

```
//rest of the imports
import * as red from './todo-list/todo/store/todo.reducers';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(red.tdReducer)
  ],
//rest of the code
```

You can check out the final version at this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-test-6w4cdq).

I haven't used this new version of `ngrx/store` before, but you can find all of the changes explained [here](http://brianflove.com/2017/09/09/updating-to-ngrx-4/).

Comment: Thanks alot! I'm not quite sure whats happening with the ActionReducerMap, but I will look it up.